# Having error with the following line

Tags: php

first error : Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php on line 15

After clicking submit button :

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php:3) in /home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php on line 28

```
<?php       
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$api_key = 'apikey';
$api_url = 'url';
$client = new jsonRPCClient($api_url);
$campaigns = $client->get_campaigns(
    $api_key,
    array (
        # find by name literally
        'name' => array ( 'EQUALS' => 'test' )
    )
);
$CAMPAIGN_ID = array_pop(array_keys($campaigns));
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $result = $client->add_contact(
    $api_key,
    array (
        'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
        'name'      => 'Test',
        'email'     => 'test@test.test',
    )
    );
$cid = "infod";
$site_url = $cid.".pokemon.com";    
header("Location: http://$site_url") ;
}

?>
```

Comment: strict standards are enabled because `E_STRICT` is part of your default `error_reporting` you need to modify the php.ini to be `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT` for error reporting.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , okay i'm blur at that part . you have answer in mind @.@?

Comment: I just said what the answer is to resolve strict standards. Your `cannot modify header information` is because you have white space being returned to the browser somewhere and it's causing this.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, i don't have a php.ini access that's a problem i can't modify also.
for the header one, is it possible i remove and place it somewhere this line

$cid = "infod";
$site_url = $cid.".pokemon.com";    
header("Location: http://$site_url") ;

Comment: You're saying you're with a web host that doesn't allow you to adjust error reporting...........?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, yeah , sad much that's why its like a cheap webhosting .

Comment: you can't do `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT)` in the top of a `.php` file?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy , i manage to force him to change but after that nothing appears in the index.php file..not even the form.

Answer (score 0):

I see from the comments you've turned strict error reporting off -- this not a good thing to do -- basically you've just hidden a genuine error, you now get a blank page and no error to help you ...

The first error:

```
Only variables should be passed by reference in   
/home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php on line 15
```

Means that you're calling a function and passing a non-variable by reference. 'Pass by reference' means that the function gets a reference to (instead of a copy of) the original variable and can modify it such that the changes are made to the variable you can see in the calling code.

So, where's the error, well line 15 looks to be this:

```
$result = $client->add_contact(
    $api_key,
    array (
        'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
        'name'      => 'Test',
        'email'     => 'test@test.test',
    )
);
```

I'm guessing that that the definition of add_contact taking the second parameter by reference (not sure why) and you're not giving it a 'real' variable to work with since you're basically building a temp array that will get thrown away.

Try building the array first:

```
$camp_arr = array (
    'campaign'  => $CAMPAIGN_ID,
    'name'      => 'Test',
    'email'     => 'test@test.test',
);

$result = $client->add_contact($api_key, $camp_arr);
```

You may also want to (later) look at the contents of $camp_arr to see what's happening.

Your second error means that headers have already been sent, this happens because you've output some text before your call to `header`, as soon as you send text the headers are sent and you cannot resend them -- this is almost certainly caused by the error message, it counts as output text and causes the headers to be sent. Note, the other common cause of this is having text or whitespace outside the `<?php ... ?>` block.

Comment: now i have this error ,
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$CAMPAIGN_ID' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/user/public_html/ref/hhhhh_hhhhh/index.php on line 13

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere -- check your semi-colons and brackets match up in the lines before that.